# What's the name for this kind of pointy/raised texture in animals?

Tags: zoology, topology

I was in a store and I saw a jackfruit, seen here https://livenaturallymagazine.com/all-about-jackfruit/ with this sort of...scaly yet round and also pointy texture.

Then, I could have sworn I saw some kind of texture like this on animals, so I tracked down a couple images, like the back of a bearded dragon https://shannonwild.photoshelter.com/image/I0000Wf4WI2Vn.V0 and the pads of an owl
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a1/94/07/a19407eff53e0fd06c48144c4541e3d8.jpg

What is the name for this semi-spiky texture, and what is the practical use of its topology?

Comment: I don't really know, however I have my suspicions. My initial guess would be the following. For the bearded dragon, I'm guessing it aids in defense. Small spikes protect against attackers. For the owl's feet, I would guess that its utility is completely different: friction. Friction helps holding on to the environment.